# bash command to copy specific lines from a file

Tags: bash

This copies the last 3 lines of outputs.txt to newfile.txt

```
tail -n 3 "outputs.txt" | cat >> newfile.txt
```

but what is the bash command to copy the (last-1)^th and (last-3)^th line of outputs.txt to newfile.txt?

Comment: You can also count the number of lines with `wc -l file` and then print them with `awk -v num=$(wc -l file) 'NR==num-1 || NR==num-3' file`

Comment: @fedorqui: thanks. Maybe it'll help someone else. In my particular case, I know the #of lines.

Comment: OK then it is even easier: `awk -v num=THE_NUMBER 'NR==num-1 || NR==num-3' file`

Comment: By the by, the `cat` there does nothing useful at all. See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following

```
tail -n 4 outputs.txt | awk 'NR ==1 || NR == 3' >> newfile.txt
```

tail takes the last 4 lines and awk selects the first and third of those, which if I understood correctly are the ones you want.

Note that in your command you don't need cat either, you can just

```
tail -n3 outputs.txt >> newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

`tac` command will do the trick.

```
tac "outputs.txt" |awk 'NR==2 || NR==4' |tac
```